# How to convert parameters to snake case in Spring Feign client GET request, when using SpringQueryMap annotation?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign

I have the following Spring Feign client:

```
public interface FeignClient {
 @GetMapping("/events/query")
 EventCollectionResponse getAplomadoEvents(@SpringQueryMap EventParameters parameters);
}
```

With `EventParameters` entity looking this way:

```
public class EventParameters {

    private String order_by;

    private String sort;

    private String start_at;

    private String end_at;
}
```

External API accepts requests in the form of snake case, but I want to name parameters using camel case in order to maintain coding standards.

Annotation @JsonProperty("order_by") did not help in this case, since we do not use JSON here because of GET method parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with the same issue and spent 4-5 hours debugging it. Actually SpringQueryMap annotation internally calls multiple encoders and none of them look for JsonProperty annotation value.
The solution is either of

1. You implement your own Encoder bean which will internally call objectmapper and there you can configure the PropertyNamingStrategy to snakecase and then provide implementation of the encode method.
2. Alternate and simple solution is create a getter for the field which you want to be in snake case for feign client and add a @Param("your_property") from feign package. e.g. @Param("start_at"). Reason why this fixes the issue is - the encoder "BeanQueryMapEncoder" looks for this @Param on the getter method, like this "method.getAnnotation(Param.class)" and if it find this annotation then it uses the values provided as an alias. Thus, it solves the issue.

So, better solution is 1st one but needs a lot of implementation and frankly i also skipped that to fix my use case. 2nd option requires to make changes in your POJO but solves the issue.

Hope it helps. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

`@FormProperty` is feign annotation that allows to set custom field names.

```
@Data
public class EventParameters {
    @FormProperty("order_by")
    private String orderBy;

    private String sort;

    @FormProperty("start_at")
    private String startAt;

    @FormProperty("end_at")
    private String endAt;
}
```